# Getting value of code editor on button click

Tags: reactjs, ace-editor

I'm just trying to simply display all the code editor's code to the console when the user clicks the **"See Code"** button.

Tried passing the value up through state but no luck. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Here is the code I got so far:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import AceEditor from "react-ace";

import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-javascript";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-monokai";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert("A code is: " + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    function onChange(codeValue) {
      console.log("change", codeValue);
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Ace Code Editor</p>
        <AceEditor
          value={`// Creating a const
const hello = "Hello World";
// Console log the variable above on the next line:
`}
          mode="javascript"
          theme="monokai"
          name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
          fontSize={16}
          onChange={onChange}
          editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
        />
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>See Code</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onChange` function doesn't update the state.

Answer (score 0):

add a ref for the editor element

```
<AceEditor ref="mainEditor"
```

and use it to get access to ace instance

```
var value = this.refs.mainEditor.editor.getValue();
```